# Migrating from Sql Server Express 2005 to express 2008

Tags: sql-server

Please advice on doing this migration, are there any issues I should be aware of. Can I do an in-place migration of the server or side-by-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Run the SQL Server Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=F5A6C5E9-4CD9-4E42-A21C-7291E7F0F852&displaylang=en) to check for any compatibility issues.

You can do side-by-side or in place.

Attaching 2005 database files to 2008 will upgrade them.

Answer (score 3):

I've migrated about half a dozen systems and had no issues.

Comment: +1 I did a couple here in our office with no snags.